# How to store data in customised-schema table with express-mysql-session

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session, cookies

I want to store the user id in `sessions` table in MySQL Database with the help of `express-mysql-session`. At first I simply set the user id in the middleware like this:

```
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import pool from "./DB/db.js";
import session from "express-session";
import mySqlSession from "express-mysql-session";

const app = express();

// session store instance, using default config
const sessionStore = new MySqlStore({}, pool);

// session config
const sessionConfig = {
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore, // storage of login sessions
};

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  req.session.user_id = 2;

  return res.json({ ok: true });
});
```

Then I found in this case the `user_id` was simply stored in the `data` column like this:

```
+----------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| session_id                       | expires    | data                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| zqUaWG0H_MvZ4Q50oE75GG9be5ZGtk6e | 1696147745 | {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"user_id":2} |
+----------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I tried to add a new column in the `sessions` table schema config:

```
const sessionStoreConfig = {
  createDatabaseTable: true,
  schema: {
    session_id: 'session_id',
    expires: 'expires',
    data: 'data',
    user_id: 'user_id',  // this is the customised column
},
};
```

And then I got an error:

```
 throw new Error('Unknown column specified ("' + userDefinedColumnName + '"). Only the following columns are configurable: "session_id", "expires", "data". Please review the documentation to understand how to correctly use this option.');
```

Seems like only these 3 columns "session_id", "expires", "data" are allowed in the `sessions` table. So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to add a column in the `sessions` table for customised data storage like the user id?
2. If the answer to the first question is "no", then I can only store the user id in such a format in the `data` column:

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"user_id":2}
```

Then how can I read the `user` id from this result when I need? Do I need a json parser to extract the "user_id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `user_id` is being correctly saved into the data field. No need to add an extra column.
If you need to access `user_id` do the following

```
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  // Store user_id in the session data
  req.session.data = {
    user_id: 2
  };

  return res.json({ ok: true });
});

// Later, when you want to access the user_id:
app.use("/someRoute", (req, res) => {
  // Parse the user_id from session data
  const userId = req.session.data.user_id;

  // Now you can use userId in your route logic
  return res.json({ userId });
});
```